# How update the quickblox user password in ios

Tags: iphone, passwords, ios10, quickblox, xcode8.2

I have to update the user password of quick blox user and the method  below is not found in new version .
Please suggest me any solution.

```
[QBRequest updateUser:currentForgotUser successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
                // User updated successfully
            } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
                // Handle error
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QBUpdateUserParameters *updateParameters = [QBUpdateUserParameters new];
updateParameters.website = @"www.mysite.com";
updateParameters.phone = @"8234234";
updateParameters.tags = @[@"man", @"golf"];

[QBRequest updateCurrentUser:updateParameters successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
    // User updated successfully
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // Handle error
}];
```

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Update_your_own_profile